# How come ISIS does not attack China or Japan or other Asian countries?

Tags: armed-conflict, terrorism, islamic-state, middle-east

How come ISIS does not attack China or Japan or other Asian countries?

Do they have no hatred for Asian countries?

Is it solely the Western society that they are after? But that wouldn't make sense: they bomb Middle Eastern targets, as well as Eastern European targets, namely, Turkey.

Comment: [Related](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10343/).

Comment: Related: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9278/why-has-mongolia-not-had-any-problems-with-political-violence-by-muslims

Comment: `ISIL does not attack Asian countries` You're wrong. For example, [Attack on Indonesia](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/asia/indonesia/12098936/Jakarta-bomb-attacks-Indonesia-terror-Isil-live.html)

Comment: [Japanese people Haruna Yukawa and Kenji Goto were murdered by IS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISIL_beheading_incidents#List_of_incidents)

Comment: In an IS video they claimed China as their No.1 enemy ... But indeed they don't attacke Asian (technically East Asian) countries

Answer (score 5):

ISIS operates in a region under direct western (including Russian) influence, where several countries have been bombed and invaded by the USA, UK, France, etc. for years. Also, from a theological and historical perspective, they can argue they are going against Christianity (which has been going against Islam for a thousand years), and conquering Europe is the one of the oldest Muslim dreams there is since the Ottomans were stopped in eastern Europe.

So it's not that they like better the Chinese and Japanese, just that they are lower on their priorities! It should be noted that the Chinese have terrorism problems with its Uyghur (Turkish speaking Muslim population living in the West) as well. Japan would be really impractical to attack as they have practically no Muslims population at all (Western Europe on the other hand is really easy to target as the Muslim population there is huge, and the refugees crisis makes it even easier for ISIS to send its armed soldiers).

Comment: The conflict of the Uyghur minority with the Chinese central state is totally out of context here.

Comment: Sorry but the "Western influence" aspect to this answer doesn't make much sense when so many of the targets of ISIS and affiliated groups are, for example, Shia muslims living in the Middle East, Kurds, Yarzidi, civilians in Mali, Nigeria... "Western influence" particularly in Saudi Arabia was a factor for Al-Qaeda, certainly, but ISIS are quite different. And conflict between China and its Uyghur minority has existed for decades.

Comment: Not only it is out of context, but it also brings purposely bring confusion between a violently persecuted minourity whose own existance is in serious danger (Uigours) with a crazy group of extremists which puts dangers to other groups' existance (IS)

Comment: @user568458 how there being other targets make it incompatible for this region to be under western influence? Or maybe you didn't understand what I mean, but Mali or Nigeria never colonized this part of the world from what I know...

Comment: About Uyghur, it's not entirely off topic as if one day ISIS wants to attack China it will be easy for them with the help of this muslim community. Thus China is more at risk than Japan. Then again, there would have been no Paris nor Brussels attacks if ISIS could not have counted on the support of local extremists there.

Comment: @Shautieh if ISIS' primary motivation is fighting Western influence, why do they spend so much time bombing Shia mosques, raiding Yarzidi villages, bombarding Kurdish towns, supporting suicide bombings in Malian marketplaces and Nigerian bus stations...? If they're responding to Western bombing campaigns, why was their latest European target *Belgium* who have had almost no involvement in any recent military action in the Middle East? You're making the mistake (common, sadly) of talking about ISIS as if they're Al-Qaeda II. They're not. ISIS' primary motivations are *territory*, & recruitment.

Comment: @user568458 as with any zealot movements it could be argued that their first and only goal is to spread their faith, and killing the Yazidis, Christians and Shias who are of no economic use in their caliphate and are unwilling to convert is a way to do it. Now for their international actions there is a difference between Mali, Nigeria, and Europe : Europe is seen as a threat to their existence while the others are just places they would like their influence to rise. Oh, and did you forget that Brussels is the capital of the EU?

Comment: Japan did send troops to Iraq though.

Comment: By the way in response to the answer, the Ottomans did occupy a large part of Eastern Europe but to a great extent the local population such as the Greeks, Bulgarians/Macedonians and Serbs were practicing their religion (Orthodoxy) without much problem.

Comment: @DylanChensky : look up "devşirme" and "janissaries". When young sons around 6 years old of Christians families were massively abducted and forcibly converted to Islam every four years, I don't think we can say these people could practice "without much problem". In fact, devşirme (along with all the dhimmi specific taxes and humiliations) is the reason many poor Christians converted to Islam all around the Balkans and elsewhere in the Ottoman empire.

Answer (score 1):

Because China didn't participate in dropping bombs on Muslims in Iraq and Afghanistan, China don't care about what happens in the middle east, they are busy fighting their own inside terrorism (for them, terrorism is anyone that have thoughts, say things, or their behavior show that they are against the rule of the communist party), so ISIS don't care about China either, they have nothing against China. USA and its allies wanted a war against Islam, they got it, that's why the terrorists bombings happen in countries that supported USA in its war.

Comment: This post is full of unbacked claims and logical flaws. At the bare minimum, it requires some prooflinks or it should be deleted altogether.

Comment: Daily reminder that the eastern province of china has monthly terrorist attacks, the atheist communist regime disallows people with beards from using public utilities, forces children to break fasts during ramadan, and bans muslims from participating in government.

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase part of the question:

> Question:  Why don't Muslims wage *jihad* within Japan?

Answer:  There are (almost) no Muslims in Japan.

According to http://www.masjid.jp/list.html, there are about 60 small mosques in Japan.  This is consistent with estimates of a Muslim population of "a few thousand", many of whom are non-practicing Japanese spouses.

The CIA's World Factbook estimates Japan's population as being about 126 million.  (https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/resources/the-world-factbook/geos/ja.html)

Answer (score -2):

Because freedom,  Christianity, Jews and Shia are their main enemy.

And they want to bring the caliphate to the whole world, well why Europe and USA target?

Because according to them these countries have given a lot of freedom to their people and interfering as well with the middle eastern concerns.

Well wait for the day when China and Japan will attack ISIS they will revert.
Well if you look at Chinese Uyghur Muslims, they are controlled very harshly by Chinese government. So it's a bit challenging to plan some big attacks in China. As there are very little Muslim population in Japan the same goes here too. As far as India is concerned, I can't say none, but a negligible fraction of Muslims support ISIS.

Comment: Well by these downwotes I understood I am wrong here, but can't I get explanation :)

Comment: Daily reminder that jews and christians are 'people of the book' and atheists (the communist party offers state enforced atheism and attempts to control and subvert religious life) are considered enemies of monotheism and Islam.

Comment: I down voted because I do not have reason to believe that they attack people based on freedom-level and you haven't given me any reason to believe that other than "some guy said so".

Comment: try not to start your post with media cliche:)